# Can I use SASS variables in Jade loops?

Tags: html, css, sass, pug

I have an array of colors stored in a SASS variable `$colors`
I am using Styledown where I can have SASS and Jade on the same page to generate some nice documentation.

The only major flaw is that I can't use SASS variables with Jade which creates a lot of duplicate code.

e.g.

I have an array of colors stored in a SASS variable called `$colors` and looping through it I generate the relevant CSS.

I want to be able to loop through the same `$colors` variable and generate some relevant HTML examples using Jade (or some other language if possible..) but I can't. I have to create a Jade-`$colors` array in order to do that. If SASS-`$colors` changes I have to remember to also change the Jade-`$colors` contents.

Is there a solution for this ? Even moving from Styledown to some other framework would be fine. As longs as I can generate CSS and HTML inside the same file and using variables that are shared amongst my CSS and HTML "loops"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sass-extract](https://github.com/jgranstrom/sass-extract) tool in order to get your sass color array as JSON, and then pass the result as jade locals to `jade.renderFile()` in order to generate html based on it.

Unfortunately due to [how jade is rendered in styledown](https://github.com/styledown/styledown/blob/master/lib/utils.js#L76), it seems to not support passing locals into the templates.

Here is a however a simple example of generating what you ask for but without styledown. Maybe it can be inspiration enough for you to find a solution that will work in your specific case. Styledown could potentially be extended to support this kind of rendering as well.

*style.scss*

```
$colors: #ff0000 #00ff00 #0000ff;
```

*template.jade*

```
p My Colors

each color in $colors.value
  div(style="color: #{color.value.hex}")
    p color: #{color.value.hex}
```

*index.js*

```
const sassExtract = require('sass-extract');
const jade = require('jade');

const style = sassExtract.renderSync({ file: './style.scss' });
const html = jade.renderFile('./template.jade', style.vars.global);

console.log(html);
```

**Outputs**

```
<p>My Colors</p>

<div style="color: #ff0000">
  <p>color: #ff0000</p>
</div>
<div style="color: #00ff00">
  <p>color: #00ff00</p>
</div>
<div style="color: #0000ff">
  <p>color: #0000ff</p>
</div>
```